# Fill form field with value

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a mapped image:

```
<img name="usaMap" src="<c:url value="/imagens/color.png"/>" usemap="#m_usaMap" border="0" width="100%">
  <map name="m_usaMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="155,94,243,259" href="<c:url value="/color/new"/>" title="Black"> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="262,94,346,259" href="<c:url value="/color/new"/>" title="Yellow">
    <area shape="rect" coords="375,82,474,276" href="<c:url value="/color/new"/>" title="Blue">
  </map>
```

I wanted to click on an image mapped, for example, yellow ... to open a new window with the "value" filled.

Example ... I click on the image title = "Yellow" ... open my form (

```
<input type="text" id="color" value="Yellow"  />
```

How do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the value property after selecting the element like so:

```
document.querySelector("#color").value = "Yellow";
```